# regex to get substring before substring

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like following,

> hi,hello,-LSB-,ASPECT,-RSB-,you

I want to extract sub-string that comes before `-LSB-,ASPECT,` till comma, `hello` in this case.

I have written regular expression like

```
\b\w+[/-/,LSB/-/,ASPECT]
```

however it extracts entire substring before and inclusing`-LSB-,ASPECT,` till start like,

> hi,hello,-LSB-,ASPECT

Any clue??

Comment: Why are you trying to use a regex for this? It's a simple case of using SubString() and IndexOf(); there's no need at all for a regex.

Comment: there may be many "," or words before -LSB-,ASPECT , also -LSB-,ASPECT can be any where in this big string, this is just example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex for this (using a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) would be

```
[^,]*(?=,-LSB-,ASPECT,)
```

**Explanation:**

```
[^,]*            # Match any number of characters except commas
(?=              # until the following regex can be matched:
 ,-LSB-,ASPECT,  # the literal text ",-LSB-,ASPECT,".
)                # (End of lookahead assertion)
```

Careful, square brackets create a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which you don't want in this case.

Comment: @TimPietzceker my mistake apologies you're right +1

Comment: looks good in expresso, but also returning a NULL character too there. Will put in my actual code ....

Answer (score 0):

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/yO2kL2)**

Try this:

```
(\w+),-LSB-,ASPECT
```